# Click inside layout redirects to another layout

Tags: android, layout

I have layout displaying question and options, if I click anywhere else than the buttons I am redirected to the default layout. I would like to know why is this happening.

**My Class**

```
package com.example.demo;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    DBHelper helper;
    SQLiteDatabase db;
    Button btnBegin,btnnext,btnredirect;
    int count = 0;
    int response = 0;

    View previouslySelectedItem = null;



    //Sub category Buttons
    Button btnaptitude5,btnaptitude4,btnaptitude3,btnaptitude2,btnaptitude1;

    String Question_ID,Title,TitleDescription,QuestionText,QuestionTemplate,QuestionImage;

    //String SubModuleQuestion_ID;

    TextView tvTitle,tvInstructions,tvQuestionText;

    RadioGroup rgtemplate4images;
    ImageView img;
     RelativeLayout aptitudesubcateg,temp4optimage, redirecttemplate;
    ListView listviewoptions;


    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.aptitude);

          aptitudesubcateg = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.aptitudesubcateg);
          temp4optimage = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.temp4optimage);

          temp4optimage.setClickable(false);

          redirecttemplate = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.redirecttemplate);

         // int position = 1;
          listviewoptions = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listViewoptions);

            listviewoptions.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {


                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,int position ,
                        long arg3) {

                    //arg1.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(
                               // R.color.pressed_color)); 

                     if (previouslySelectedItem != null)
                        {
                            previouslySelectedItem.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
                                    //getResources().getColor(R.color.pressed_color));
                        }

                     arg1.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
                               // getResources().getColor(R.color.default_color));

                        previouslySelectedItem = arg1;
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                     Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),String.valueOf(position+1), Toast. LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                     response = position+1;

                }
            });



         aptitudesubcateg.setVisibility(View.GONE);
         temp4optimage.setVisibility(View.GONE);
         redirecttemplate.setVisibility(View.GONE);


        btnaptitude1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnaptitude1);
        btnaptitude2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnaptitude2);
        btnaptitude3 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnaptitude3);
        btnaptitude4 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnaptitude4);
        btnaptitude5 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnaptitude5);

        btnredirect = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnredirect);


        btnaptitude1.setOnClickListener(this);
        btnaptitude2.setOnClickListener(this);
        btnaptitude3.setOnClickListener(this);
        btnaptitude4.setOnClickListener(this);
        btnaptitude5.setOnClickListener(this);
        btnredirect.setOnClickListener(this);

        helper=new DBHelper(this);


//addQuestion();

        btnBegin = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnBeginAptitude);

        btnBegin.setOnClickListener(this);

        btnnext = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnNxtTemp4optnsImg);

        btnnext.setOnClickListener(this);

    }


     public void addQuestion()
        {
            {

                // Add Record with help of ContentValues and DBHelper class object
                ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
            //  values.put(DBHelper.Q_ID, "a");


                values.put(DBHelper.Module_ID,"1");
                values.put(DBHelper.SubModule_ID,"2");
                values.put(DBHelper.Question_ID,"2" );
                values.put(DBHelper.SubModuleQuestion_ID,"1");
                values.put(DBHelper.Title,"Test");
                values.put(DBHelper.TitleDescription, "Demo");
                values.put(DBHelper.QuestionText, "I find it easy to discuss any topic with a new person");
                values.put(DBHelper.QuestionImage, "user.png");
                values.put(DBHelper.QuestionTemplate, "template4options.xml");
                values.put(DBHelper.CorrectOptionID, "1");

                // Call insert method of SQLiteDatabase Class and close after
                // performing task
                db = helper.getWritableDatabase();
                db.insert(DBHelper.TableQuestionMaster, null, values);
                db.close();


                Toast.makeText(this, "Question Added Successfully",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


                }
        }

     public int getcount(String moduleID, String SubModuleID)
     {
         count = 0;
         String selectQuery = "Select * from TableQuestionMaster where Module_ID = "+moduleID+" AND SubModule_ID ="+SubModuleID;

            SQLiteDatabase db = helper.getReadableDatabase();
            Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
            count =  cursor.getCount();

            Toast.makeText(this, String.valueOf(count) ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 

            cursor.close();
            db.close();

    return count; 
     }

       private void Getoptions() {
            // database handler
            DBHelper db = new DBHelper(getApplicationContext());

            // Spinner Drop down elements
             List<String> options = db.getAllOptions(Question_ID);

            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, options);

            listviewoptions.setAdapter(adapter);

            //Toast.makeText(this,"",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }



       public void getAllQuestionsAptitude(String moduleID, String SubModuleID,String SubModuleQuestion_ID){



           SQLiteDatabase db = helper.getReadableDatabase();
           Cursor c = null;

           if (count>0)
            {

           //   SubModuleQuestion_ID = "1";
                   String selectQuestion = "Select * from TableQuestionMaster where Module_ID = "+moduleID+" AND SubModule_ID ="+SubModuleID+" AND SubModuleQuestion_ID ="+SubModuleQuestion_ID;
                      c = db.rawQuery(selectQuestion, null);
            if (c.moveToFirst()) {
                do {


                    Question_ID = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("Question_ID")); 

                    Title = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("Title"));


                    TitleDescription = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("TitleDescription"));


                    QuestionText = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("QuestionText"));


                    QuestionTemplate = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("QuestionTemplate"));


                    QuestionImage = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("QuestionImage"));

                    Toast.makeText(this,Question_ID+" "+Title+" "+TitleDescription+" "+QuestionText+" "+QuestionTemplate+" "+QuestionImage,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    Getoptions();

                } while (c.moveToNext());        
            }
            }
            else

            {
                 Toast.makeText(this,"NO question to display",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }


            // closing connection
            c.close();
            db.close();

        }

       public void displayquestions()
       {
           Toast.makeText(this,"count on display Q is"+ count,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
           if (count >0)
           {
               getAllQuestionsAptitude("1","2",String.valueOf(count));

                    aptitudesubcateg.setVisibility(View.GONE);                            
                    temp4optimage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); 

                    tvTitle = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvTitleTemplate4optoinsImage);
                    tvInstructions = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvInstructionstemplate4);
                    tvQuestionText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvQuestionTextTemplate4ImageAptitude);

                    img = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageViewtemplate4optionsAptitude);

                    tvTitle.setText(Title);
                    tvInstructions.setText(TitleDescription);
                    tvQuestionText.setText(QuestionText);

                    String imgName = QuestionImage; // specify here your image name fetched from db
                    String uri = "drawable/" + imgName;
                    int icon = getResources().getIdentifier(uri, "drawable", getPackageName());
                    img.setImageResource(icon);


                    //NextQuestion();
           }
           else
           {
               aptitudesubcateg.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                  temp4optimage.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                  redirecttemplate.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
               Toast.makeText(this,"NO question to display",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
           }


       }

       public void NextQuestion()
       {
           if (count>0)
           {
           count = count - 1;
           saveQuestion();

           }
           else
           {
               aptitudesubcateg.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                  temp4optimage.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                  redirecttemplate.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

           }

       }

       public void saveQuestion()
       {
           if (response != 0)
           {
            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
            //  values.put(DBHelper.Q_ID, "a");

                values.put(DBHelper.StudentID,"1" );
                values.put(DBHelper.R_QuestionID,Question_ID);
                values.put(DBHelper.QuestOptionID,String.valueOf(response));

                db = helper.getWritableDatabase();
                db.insert(DBHelper.TABLEResponse, null, values);
                db.close();


                Toast.makeText(this, "Response saved Successfully",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                  displayquestions();

           }
           else
           {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Please Select an option",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
           }

       }







    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        if (v==btnBegin)
        {
             aptitudesubcateg.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
              temp4optimage.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        }       
            if (v== btnaptitude1)
            {               
                      getcount("1", "1");
                    //  displayquestions();        

            }

            if (v== btnaptitude2)
            {
                  getcount("1", "2");
                  displayquestions();

            }

            if (v== btnaptitude3)
            {
                  getcount("1", "3");
                //  displayquestions();


            }

            if (v== btnaptitude4)
            {

                 getcount("1", "4");
            //   displayquestions();
            }

            if (v== btnaptitude5)
            {

                 getcount("1", "5");
            //   displayquestions();
            }

            if (v== btnnext)
            {
                NextQuestion();
            }

            if (v==btnredirect)
            {
                  aptitudesubcateg.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                  temp4optimage.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                  redirecttemplate.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }


        }



    }
```

**My Design**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/back" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvInstructionsAptitude"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/tvQuestionTextTemplate4Image"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/TextView01"
        android:layout_marginTop="93dp"
        android:text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam nibh ex, elementum non bibendum ac, consequat a sem. Proin aliquet arcu id lacus interdum, sed fermentum neque sollicitudin. Vestibulum mauris massa, vulputate tincidunt quam vel, egestas tincidunt nisi. Ut ut nulla sagittis, aliquet lectus vitae, pretium nisi. Duis maximus, magna vitae ultricies consectetur, ex felis congue turpis, id scelerisque nisl ex at turpis. Aenean dui sapien, euismod at sem non, rhoncus molestie urna. Mauris condimentum risus felis, nec iaculis orci accumsan nec. Vivamus pharetra ultricies quam a aliquam. Praesent facilisis turpis malesuada massa interdum consequat. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Integer efficitur nibh risus, ac mattis mi porta ut. Nam leo ex, pulvinar eu orci vel, pretium maximus velit. Pellentesque rhoncus sapien felis, in cursus eros malesuada imperdiet."
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvQuestionTextTemplate4Image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="53dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:text="Instructions"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TextView01"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/tvQuestionTextTemplate4Image"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/tvQuestionTextTemplate4Image"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="36dp"
        android:text="Time : 10 Mins"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnBeginAptitude"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/tvInstructionsAptitude"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/tvInstructionsAptitude"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tvInstructionsAptitude"
        android:layout_marginTop="42dp"
        android:text="Begin" />

    <include
        android:id="@+id/aptitudesubcateg"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"

        layout="@layout/aptitudesubcategory" />

    <include
        android:id="@+id/temp4optimage"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        layout="@layout/template4optionsimage" />

      <include
        android:id="@+id/redirecttemplate"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        layout="@layout/redirecttoaptitudesubmodule" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Not redirect it's replace right ?

Comment: Yes.. It shouldnt redirect at all... If i click on blank space in the screen it replaces to sub category page....

Comment: As u can see i have included few <include> tags

Comment: Ok... Its working fine on my end... pls give it a try

Comment: can you check in `onClick()`, which of your case is calling? I am trying to understand which layout is replacing which layout while you click 'anywhere except buttons'?

Answer (score 1):

I once faced an error that a click on the white space of Fragment B caused an onClick event in the previous (underlying) Fragment A. Your problem sounds similar to me, so i am assuming that you are clicking an "invisible" button of one of the included, but invisible, layouts.

So please try to add this to the parent RelativeLayout:

```
android:clickable="true"
```

Answer (score 1):

**Reason** : That's because your previous screen has touch/click listener on parent of sub-parent, and when your view doesn't have one of that it passes that event to parent/super view.

**Solutions** are many,

1) Add line `android:clickable="true"` in your current activity/fragment's parent view

2) Add below code in your current activity/fragment's `onCreate()`

```
 root.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            return true;
        }
    });
```

3) Add `android:onClick=temp` to your view's parent layout and make one `temp(View v)` method in your class.

4) if it's a fragment then before transition `commit()` add this line `.addToBackStack(null)`

Answer (score 1):

Try to call in you onCreate() method the setEnable(false) and/or setClickable(false) mothods of the views other than the buttons.

But most of all, you should check the ids, not the views directly:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    int id = v.getId();
    switch(id){
        case R.id.btnaptitude1Id:
        ...
        break;
        case R.id.btn1:
        ...
    }
```

If you don't like the id, at least you should use the "equals()" method:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if(v.equals(btnBegin){
        ...
    }
    if(v.equals(btnaptitude1){
        ...
    }
    ...
```

See if it works with this